# id as 'datepicker' being replaced by model field 'due_date' while using datepicker in rails form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have the following in a form,

```
 <div class="row">
      <%= t.label :name, 'Due Date' %><br>
      <%= t.text_field :due_date, id: 'datepicker' %>
 </div>
```

The `id` attribute is required to show jquery `datepicker`. But rails replaces the `id` attribute value with the `field name` of the form i.e due_date. This causes validation error for first time date selection but works fine in second time selection.It should not show validation error when date is selected for first time.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you get if you put it in curly braces?
`<%= t.text_field :due_date, {id: 'datepicker'} %>` if not can't you set it up using a class, that is what I do with datepicker.  Then it works if you need multiple datepickers on the same form

Comment: I tried using both ways but it did not work.Replacing 'datepicker' id with model id in jquery.ui.datepicker.js file is not logical.Giving class name doesn't fire the jquery action.

Comment: I didn't say replace the datepicker id with the model id, I said use a class.

`<%= t.text_field :due_date, class: 'datepicker' %>`

and in jquery `$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();`

Comment: @Baloo your suggestion seems good but here it do not fire jquery on specifying class: 'datepicker'. It seems it wants id: 'datepicker' to fire the jquery action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope `t` is a form object, then Try with:

```
<div class="row">
      <%= t.label :name, 'Due Date' %><br>
      <%= t.text_field :due_date, :value => "", :id=>"datepicker" %>
 </div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The :value need some value instead of empty string. In that way it finally worked for me. Thank you.